# Form solution for SharePoint 2013

Tags: forms, sharepoint-2013, infopath, infopath-forms-services

I would like to create some electronic form solution for SharePoint 2013, I am trying to explore some different option aside from InfoPath 2013, can you please recommend something alternative or better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good list of alternatives to InfoPath by Mark Jones: http://list.ly/list/EKk-infopath-forms-alternatives

Full disclosure: I work for PDF Share Forms and we are featured in this list.

Choosing the right forms product can be a tough decision and you need to figure out what functionality you are really looking for. Main advantage of PDF Share Forms is that you can reuse existing forms/documents as form templates and potentially save loads of time because there is no need to design from scratch every time. Also, in the process you get a tangible document - PDF form that is not just bunch of data in your SharePoint. It is an international standard that is not going away anytime soon.

Learn more here: http://www.pdfshareforms.com/